# Repeat Last Action Doesn't Work

Tags: customization, settings, keymap

So yeah, after the last few updates, shift + R (the repeat function) doesn't work. For instance, if I duplicate a cube, move it to the right of intial cube and press Shift + R, nothing happens. I'm running the most current version of Blender on Steam, 3.6 and still have this issue and the last few updates it stopped working. Not sure why. Also, I've changed the keymapping to something other than shift + R. This doesn't work either. And finally I've used F3 and tried to use the repeat function there.. nothing. Can't find anything on the subject that's recent on the internet involving this. Anyone know what's up? I've since downloaded Blender 3.6 from Blender's website and did a fresh install with no addons added with default settings.. same thing.

Comment: I've just used `Shift`+`R` (for a different reason) in 3.6.2 and it works just as expected. Perhaps it is a bug? If you open the _Preferences_ > _Keymap_ and search for 'repeat', what does it give as result for _Repeat Last_?

Comment: It says Shift R.. I've tried replacing it with another key combination and it doesn't work no matter what I set it to. I've just reinstalled windows on a clean installation and that didn't help either. The problem still persists. I get the same problem whether I'm using Blender's standalone version or the Steam version of Blender.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't sure how the function worked.. I've got it figure out, thanks.

Comment: I first thought about explaining to you how to use it, but since you said this happened "after the last few updates", I assumed it worked before and you know how.

Comment: Yeah what happened was I was trying to copy the cube then using the widget to move the new cube over on the axis then using shift + R. Apparently you have to use the G key for grabbing and not the widget.

Comment: I don't know how you copied the cube: `Ctrl`+`C` and `Ctrl`+`V` or duplicate it with `Shift`+`D`? And what did you want to repeat, the copying, the moving or both? Because `Shift`+`R` repeats only the last action. So, no matter if you used the widget (=gizmo?) or `G`, in both cases the last action was moving, not copying (and repeating the movement with `Shift`+`R` works for me in both cases). If you want to repeat copying **and** moving, you have to use duplicating with `Shift`+`D` because then you can directly press e.g. `X` to move on X and make this a single action which can be repeated.